# Adding System.ValueTuple 4.3.1 causes too many redirects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5, identityserver4

I added System.ValueTuple to a MVC application and after a rebuild results in the TOO MANY REDIRECTs error.  I am testing IdentityServer4 and need to install IdentityModel which needs this package.  Any thoughts on how do debug why this package is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

Apparently, VS2017 didn't hook up the site correctly in IIS to debug so I was unable to see the errors initially.  Once I figured that piece out I was able to see that yes, I was in an infinite loop of exceptions.  Exception bubbled up to the exception page which through an exception and bingo in a loop.

The original exception stated the site couldn't find System.Runtime.  Added that from nugget after that fact corrected the issue.   It looks like you have to add this package at the very end as well.  Not before.

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I am having the same problem. However, adding System.Runtime has not solved the issue. What did you do to your IIS to be able to debug the error?